# coefficient by $x^{n-1}$ in Chebyshew polynominals

Tags: polynomials, recursion, chebyshev-polynomials

Calculate coefficient by $x^{n-1}$ in Chebyshew polynominal of the first kind $T_n$, defined as:
$$
T_0(x)=1\\
T_1(x)=x\\
T_n(x)=2x\cdot T_{n-1}(x)-T_{n-2}(x)
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coefficient by $x^{n-1}$ of $T_n(x)$ is $0$. One can use induction:

- $n=0$ and $n=1$ are clear.
- Assume it is true for $0\leq m <n$. Let $a$ be the coefficient by $x^{n-2}$ of $T_{n-1}(x)$. By the induction hypothesis, $a=0$ From the expression, $T_n(x)=2xT_{n-1}-T_{n-2}(x)$, we know that the coefficient by $x^{n-1}$ of $T_n(x)$ is $2a$, which is $0$, as wanted.

**Note:** For this to work you should also prove that $T_n(x)$ has degree $n$, which may also be done by induction.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Prove by induction that the degree of $T_n$ is $n$ and that the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ in $T_n$ is zero.

Actually, $T_n$ has only even powers when $n$ is even and only odd powers when $n$ is odd.

Comment: The coefficient of $x^{n-2}$ is more interesting. See https://oeis.org/A001792